# Route to CSS tabs in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a view in a rails environment with three tabs that loads three data from three models. Users can navigate around the data, and drill down into specific records. However, when they save a record I can only route back to the page, which obviously displays the first tab

I want to know how to route back to a specific tab rather than just reloading the page which displays the first tab.

The tabs are displayed with css.

For example, I have a model Employee. As one of the sub screens of Employee I want to display a performance screen. This performance screen will display 3 tabs.

I have tried using tabulous, but I need the tabs to appear in a specific point in the page, whereas tabulous seems to want its code inserted into the layout file. Tabulous seems overkill and also would limit me if I wanted to do this type of functionality on other screens as it only supports one set of tabs.

Hope that makes some sense.

Comment: Hmm, the only thing I know of, that you can append the tab number to the URL, like `#tab-1`. Depends on what JS plugin/technique you use for the tabs. This causes jQuery UI tabs to switch after the page is loaded. Does that help somehow?

Comment: like @SebastianWramba said, use javascript for that issue.